# Meaning of speech bubble in desktop Twitter?

Tags: twitter

In the Twitter desktop version, what does a speech bubble mean under your tweet?

[image]

I thought it might mean "there are replies to your tweet". But when I click on the tweet, nothing shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reply, but apparently the reply didn't show up immediately:

[image: Reply to @bemmu]

The speech bubble is also a button, allowing you to send a reply tweet.

Answer (score 1):

You're right; it does mean replies. However, if a reply is deleted after it's posted, the reply itself will disappear, but it will still be counted in the number of replies.

For example, if two people reply to your tweet and then one of them deletes their reply, the number next to the speech bubble would be "2" but you would only see one reply.

There are three possible reasons why you might see a "1" but no actual reply:

- The reply was deleted
- The reply was posted by someone whose tweets are protected
- The reply was posted by someone who has since blocked you, or who you've blocked or muted

For more details about replies, see this Twitter Help Center page:

https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/mentions-and-replies